# Prove that continuous functions conserve separability.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a separable topological space, $Y$ a topological space and $f:X \to Y$ continuous surjective function.  Prove that $Y$ is separable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n$ be a countable dense set of $X$. Claim $f(x_n)$ is a dense set for $Y$.

Indeed pick $y\in Y$, then there is $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Now we can find $x_{k_n}$ such that $x_{k_n}\rightarrow y$ and from continuity $f(x_{k_n}) \rightarrow f(x)=y$. So we conclude the claim and hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be a dense subset of $X.$ The cardinal of $f(D)$ cannot exceed the cardinal of $D.$

If $f(D)$ is not dense in $Y,$ then $E=Y$ \ $\overline {f(D)}$ is a non-empty open subset of $Y.$  And f is a continuous  surjection, so $f^{-1}(E)$ is a non-empty open subset of $X.$ But   $D\cap f^{-1}(E)$ is empty, contradicting the density of $D$ in $X.$

Therefore $f(D)$ must be dense in $Y.$

Comment: Very nice. I find this quite elegant

Comment: The least infinite cardinal $K$ such that the space $X$ has a dense subset of cardinal $\leq K$ ( or equal to $K,$  if X doesn't have a finite dense subset) is called the density of $X,$ denoted $d(X). $ So if $Y$ is a continuous image of $X$, then $d(Y)\leq d(X).$